# Cucumber integration test Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing

I have ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 and when I run the feature scenario. I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:129:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:73:in `response_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:41:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:476:in `raw_execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:454:in `execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:177:in `quit'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:40:in `quit'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:156:in `quit'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-0.4.0/lib/capybara/driver/selenium_driver.rb:88
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very old version of `selenium-webdriver` (0.02). A lot has been fixed since then so you are likely to have a lot of issues with it. Also old versions don't support modern browsers so if you want to test on modern version of Firefox, you should update this gem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Selenium is having trouble connecting to your test browser. I had this problem when using the latest Firefox.

When I downgraded to FF 3.0.6 it started working.